# webpack not rebuilding dist folder on change

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-code, hot-reload

I am following the tutorial on edx.org for the Azure Skills Toolkit (Microsoft: DEV224x)
https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DEV224x+1T2018a/course/

I am using Win10 and VSCode

I already have node, npm, yeoman and aspnetcore-spa globally installed.  I have followed the course notes to set up the template app

create new folder

```
dotnet new angular
npm install
dotnet start
```

This dotnet start generates the dist folders in wwwroot and CilentApp and runs the app on the local server on port 5000 - so far so good.

When I make changes to the angular xxx.component.html files and refresh the browser, the changes are not showing (the course notes say that they should be). Even if I stop the server and restart they are not there.  If I delete or rename the dist folders then they are rebuilt and the change then shows.  looking at the files in the dist folder, the angular codes gets compiled into server-main.js

Why is webpack not updating the dist files on hot reload and/or on server start?